# is there any Class in Qt for pulling data out of HTML?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

the Qt documentation says

> The Qt XML Module is provided for compatibility with older code. It
>   has been superseded by the QXMLStreamReader and QXMLStreamWriter
>   classes in the Qt Core Module.

I think we can use QDom*  class to get data out of HTML  before this claim ,although I never used it.
does this claim mean we can use QXmlStreamReader for pulling data out of HTML ?
I don't know the difference between XML and HTML.

Comment: Since you tagged your questions also with pyqt and pyside, it's maybe worth noting that there's also a variety of xml/html parsers available in python, e.g. `beautifulsoup` seems to be fairly popular.

Answer (score 0):

XML stands for "Extensible Markup Language", whereas HTML stands for Hypertext Markup Language. In simple terms, they are not the same, or at least not used for the same purpose.

XML [is a markup language that defines a set of rules for encoding documents in a format which is both human-readable and machine-readable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

HTML [is the standard markup language used to create Web pages.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)

Looking at html and xml, they appear similar in that they both include tokens to define elements, though the elements used by HTML are of a fixed set, unlike XML whose elements are the meta-data of the document in which the elements reside.

Since XML elements can be named freely, unlike HTML, HTML can be added to a DOM document. As for being able to use QXmlStreamReader, according to [this thread](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7382), it appears that you can, but note that the OP of that question has wrapped the html in an XML tag, which I expect will be required in order for the Dom document to accept parsing the data.